# Select2 multiple selected with Thymeleaf in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, jquery-select2

I have a select field like this:

```html
<select id="genre-selection" style="min-width: 500px;" multiple="multiple" name="genre-selector" > 
   <option th:each="genre : ${genres}" th:value="${genre.id}" th:selected="${genre.name}" th:text="${genre.name}">Genre</option>
</select>
```

In this field I use this `List<Genres>`:

```
List<Genres> Genres = new ArrayList<Genres>();
for ( Genres s : genreDao.findAll()) {
   Genres.add( s );
} 
model.addAttribute( "genres", Genres );
```

This will show all Genres from my database.
I want that show all Genres but selected my saved `MovieGenres`.
For this I have another `List<Genres>` at the moment:

```
List<Genres> GenreName = new ArrayList<Genres>();
    for ( Genres s : movieDao.findOne( id ).getGenres() ) {
        GenreName.add( s );
    }
```

But I don't know how can I select only the deposited Genes from the Movie.

Comment: what do you mean "but seleced my saved MovieGenres"? Where does that "id" come from? Where is the selection made? Remember thymeleaf does everything on the server. If the user selects smth in the browser, you need javascript code to do smth about it

Comment: i have a Movie Table, Genre Table and a Movie_Genre Table.. and the id comes from the database table.

the id is the movie id from the database.. for example id is 1 that have genre 1,2,3

and i want that all genres will show in the select box but the 1,2,3 will selected

Comment: From what I see, you're selecting all genres now (by giving a value to the 'selected' HTML attribute ). If you add genreNames to your model, you'll be able to do smth like th:selected="${genreNames.contains(genre)} ?: _" . By using this, when it contains the genre, 'selected' will be present. If the genre isn't contained, 'selected' will be skipped. See details on the no-operation token http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#the-no-operation-token